# Why is the random variable $U\mathbb{I}_{U \ge 0.5}$ neither continuous nor discrete?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Quoting from *A Second Course in Probaiblity*

> Let $U\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$. Define $V = U\mathbb{I}_{U > 0.5}$. This is neither continuous nor discrete.

Why is this statement true? I am having some trouble "picturing" the random variable $V$. I tried to find the cumulative function of $V$:

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(V < x) &= \mathbb{P}(U \mathbb{I}_{U > 0.5} < x)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(U\mathbb{I} < x \mid U < 0.5) \mathbb{P}(U < 0.5) + \mathbb{P}(U\mathbb{I} < x\mid U \ge 0.5) \mathbb{P}(U \ge 0.5)\\
&= \int_0^{0.5} 1 \,du + \int_{0.5}^1 1 \,du \frac{\int_{0.5}^x 1\,du}{\int_{0.5}^1 1\,du}\\
&= \frac{0.25}{2} + \frac{x^2 - 0.25}{2}
\end{align}

And I do not see anything special about this?

Comment: Here is what that definition of $V$ means: if $U<1/2$ then $V=0$, and if $U \ge 1/2$ then $V=U$.  So, can you show $V$ is not continuous?  Can you show $V$ is not discrete?  Show us your thoughts on each of the two parts.

Comment: It is called a random variable with a "mixed" distribution (not to be confused with mixture distributions).

Comment: @GEdgar I actually tried to find $f(x) = \mathbb{P}( V < x)$ and I notice nothing particularly strange about it?

Comment: If $x\leqslant0$, $P(V<x)=0$. If $x>0$, $P(V<x)\geqslant P(V=0)=\frac12$. Thus, the CDF has a jump at $x=0$.

Comment: You may notice that your formula for $P(V<x)$ is not a probability distribution over all real numbers. The formula is correct only for $0.5\leq x\leq 1.$ Did you try to find $P(V<x)$ outside that interval? If not, then of course you did not see its "special" features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably no one will notice so I will write something for my own notes purpose. I was thinking about the random variable where $X$ has density $f_X (x)$ and its support is $\mathbb{R}$. Let $Y$ be defined as
$$Y = X\mathbb{I}_{X < c} + c\mathbb{I}_{X \ge c}$$
, and I was interested in finding the expectation.

I was wrong in looking for a nice pdf for $Y$ and as others pointed out, if I started with cdf, I would realize that there is a jump that makes things bad in a sense that we cannot take derivative there.

To calculate $\mathbb{E}(Y)$, the easiest way I could come up with is to use "law of unconscious statistician", namely,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(Y) &= \mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{I}_{X < c} + c \mathbb{I}_{X \ge c})\\
&= \mathbb{E}(X\mathbb{I}_{X < c}) + \mathbb{E}(c \mathbb{I}_{X \ge c})\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R} x \mathbb{I}_{x <c} f_X(x) \,dx + \int_\mathbb{R} c\mathbb{I}_{X\ge c} f_X(x) \,dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^c x f_X (x) \,dx + \int_c^\infty c f_X (x) \,dx
\end{align}
, which isn't that surprising.